# docker port mapping ignored when adding volumes to the run command

Tags: node.js, docker

When I start my docker container with:

```
docker run -it -d -p 8081:8080 --name ${APP_CONTAINER_NAME} ${APP_IMAGE}
```

I can access my web application just fine in my browser on: `localhost:8081`

But if I instead run it with the two volumes below:

```
docker run -it -d -p 8081:8080 -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules --name ${APP_CONTAINER_NAME} ${APP_IMAGE}
```

The port mapping is ignored - I cannot access it at `localhost:8081` but I can access it at `localhost:8080`.

My dockerfile has:

```
FROM node:8-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add bash
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

Why does adding the volumes to the second docker run command ignore the port mapping from 8081 to 8080?

As suggested below running *without* `-d` (but with volumes):

```
docker run -it -p 8081:8080 -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules --name ${APP_CONTAINER_NAME} ${APP_IMAGE}
```

gives:

```
Starting up http-server, serving dist
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.17.0.2:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

But I cannot access it on `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8081` even though the container is indeed running:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
603b1bf02d58        app-image      "http-server dist"   11 seconds ago      Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   app-container
```

When I instead run it *without* volumes but still map to 8081 it works:

```
Starting up http-server, serving dist
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.17.0.2:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

and I can access it on `localhost:8081`. So something in the application must be messed up when adding the volumes just not sure what. I have also tried to run:

```
docker volume prune
```

before starting the container but it has no effect. Any ideas why creating the volumes prevents the application from being accessed?

Comment: You're not exposing any container ports on `localhost:8080`, so if you're connecting to something there it has nothing to do with the container you've just started. Are you certain that your volume mounts aren't causing your container to **fail**? That would explain the lack of anything listening on port 8081.

Comment: Temporarily take out the `docker run -d` option.  Does the container actually start up?  Does mounting an arbitrary anonymous volume over your project’s `node_modules` directory cause problems?

Comment: I have tried to do that see updated post, the container does start when mounting the volumes but for some reason the app is not accessible.